# Getting error with MySql and Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm programming a little Application on Android Studio and I am trying to make a Login and Register with MySQL since i got really mad with Google's Firebase.

My Problem is that i still get the exact same error and i don't know what the problem is.

The Error Code is in this Class and the Code says "Error with Response":

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText etusername;
private EditText etemail;
private EditText etpassword;
private EditText etconfirmpw;
private Button btnsetupnext;
private AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
private String username;
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;
private String email;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String register_url = "http://192.168.179.58:81/chatty/register.php";
private SessionHandler session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

    etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accinfousername);
    etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accinfoemail);
    etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accinfopassword);
    etconfirmpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accinfopasswordconfirm);
    btnsetupnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.accinfoprogress);


    btnsetupnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    //Retrieve the data entered in the edit texts

                    username = etusername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    password = etpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    confirmPassword = etconfirmpw.getText().toString().trim();
                    email = etemail.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (validateInputs()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnsetupnext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        registerUser();
                    }

        }
    });
}

private void displayLoader() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SetupActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Signing Up.. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

/**
 * Launch Dashboard Activity on Successful Sign Up
 */
private void sendUserToVerification() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetupVerificationActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}

private void registerUser() {
    displayLoader();
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    try {
        //Populate the request parameters
        request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        request.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, register_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        //Check if user got registered successfully
                        if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                            //Set the user session
                            session.loginUser(username,email);
                            sendUserToVerification();

                        }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 1){
                            //Display error message if username is already existsing
                            etusername.setError("Username already taken!");
                            etusername.requestFocus();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnsetupnext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnsetupnext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error with JSONObject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnsetupnext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error with Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
}

/**
 * Validates inputs and shows error if any
 * @return
 */
private boolean validateInputs() {
    if (KEY_EMPTY.equals(username)) {
        etusername.setError("Username cannot be empty");
        etusername.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if (KEY_EMPTY.equals(email)) {
        etemail.setError("Email cannot be empty");
        etemail.requestFocus();
        return false;

    }

    if (KEY_EMPTY.equals(password)) {
        etpassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
        etpassword.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if (KEY_EMPTY.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        etconfirmpw.setError("Confirm Password cannot be empty");
        etconfirmpw.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }

    if(!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        etconfirmpw.setError("Password and Confirm Password doesn't match");
        etconfirmpw.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

}

Here are the importent PHP Scripts:

Register.php:

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && 
isset($input['email'])){
$username = $input['username'];
$password = $input['password'];
$email = $input['email'];

//Check if user already exist
if(!userExists($username)){

    //Get a unique Salt
    $salt         = getSalt();

    //Generate a unique password Hash
    $passwordHash = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    //Query to register new user
    $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO member(username, email, password_hash, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$email,$passwordHash,$salt);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response["status"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "User created";
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User exists";
}
}
else{
$response["status"] = 2;
$response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Then the db_conncect.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "chatty"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

And the functions.php:

```
<?php
$random_salt_length = 32;

function userExists($username){
$query = "SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = ?";
global $con;
if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

return false;
}

function getSalt(){
global $random_salt_length;
return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($random_salt_length));
}

function concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt){
global $random_salt_length;
if($random_salt_length % 2 == 0){
    $mid = $random_salt_length / 2;
}
else{
    $mid = ($random_salt_length - 1) / 2;
}

return
substr($salt,0,$mid - 1).$password.substr($salt,$mid,$random_salt_length - 
1);

}
?>
```

And the MySQL Database is structured like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL unique,
`password_hash` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`salt` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: "Error with response" is a bit broad. Can you give us the value of `error.getMessage()` on the line before?

Comment: it says nothing but thanks for taking care

Comment: Even if you dump it to logcat instead of as a toast?

Comment: I found nothing in logcat